# Ext 3.4.0 simplify Data-Grid Dom

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs

We´re using ext3.4.0 to display database output as grid. When a lot of rows are generated some browsers run into script timeout. I´m suggesting it´s because of a quite complex generated dom structure:

```
<div class="x-grid3-row row-einfach" style="width:1718px;">
<table class="x-grid3-row-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:1718px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-0 x-grid3-cell-first " tabindex="0" style="width: 78px;">
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-0" unselectable="on">4</div>
</td>
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-1 " tabindex="0" style="width: 78px;">
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-1" unselectable="on">4</div>
</td>
```

…

would be the output for this:
[image]

where every row is a div with a table in it. Can this be simplified f.e. by writing / Using a thiner template?

thanks,

t book

Comment: You could try to speed things up, by using by Ext.util.Observable.suspendEvents() and Ext.util.Observable.resumeEvents()!

Comment: thanks I will dive into the documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot simplify this markup. Even when you would succeed, it would probably be at the price of loosing functionality of the grid.

Are you sure there is not another issue with your code ? Did you find where it hangs exactly, using the console ?

Maybe it's not an option for you, but it seems ExtJs 4 is more efficient. The markup will not be simpler, but it should not make the browser hang, even with grids that have hundreds of rows.

Comment: Thanks Lorenz for your reply, right unfortunately I cannot update to ExtJS 4. Profiling the app shows the DB query is quite fast. What really takes long is to render the data in datagrid. In other words the data is already received but I guess building the dom takes much to long. This eats about 80mb in Firefox. Don´t know what else to do as the clients rejects paging :(

Comment: Sorry, I never used extjs 3.4, so I cannot help you further.

Comment: I think buffered renderer was not available in ExtJs 3.4. It would be a good solution. Maybe you just have to convince your customer that a paging grid would be the solution.

Comment: yes, right will check again if I can update to ext4 or go back to paging (which was in use already)